# Insert or Delete rows in Excel

Tags: vba, insert, range, rows

I have one Excel file where I want to readjust number of rows by comparing the current number of rows in my tab with those of another tab. 
So when my range range is less than the one I'm comparing with I want to insert the difference so that the two ranges will have the same number of rows.
Respectively I want if my current range is more than the other one to delete rows.

So far I have this code which is working with small ranges. But when it is comparing for example 100 with 1000 is crushing.

*nbr is the absolute difference between the number of rows in my working file and the number of rows in the database. So in other words it will always will be the number of rows to be inserted or deleted.

This is the code I am using:

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WORKING FILE")
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATABASE")
Dim nbr As Integer
Dim CellDB As Integer
Dim CellWRK As Integer
Dim i As Integer


CellDB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATABASE").Range("A1").Value

CellWRK = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Range("A1").Value

nbr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WORKING FILE").Range("A2").Value


If CellWRK < CellDB Then

With Sheets("WORKING FILE")
For i = 1 To nbr
        Rows(22).Insert
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End With
ElseIf CellWRK > CellDB Then

With Sheets("WORKING FILE")
For i = 1 To nbr
        Rows(22).Delete
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End With
```

Comment: the `if` only needs to control the delete or insert, so there is a lot of redundant code there, your loop  is the same, so inside one loop have `If CellWRK < CellDB Then Rows(22).Insert else Rows(22).Delete`

Comment: I also include a third condition in the end for the case where CellWRK = CellDB where I have a pop-up message. So I include in the end the Else function.

Comment: same logic `if a>b then insert elseif a<b delete else a=b then msgbox end if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified your `If` statement, give it a try.

```
If CellWRK < CellDB Then
    For i = 1 To nbr
        CellWRK.Rows(22).Insert
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ElseIf CellWRK > CellDB Then
    For i = 1 To nbr
        CellWRK.Rows(22).Delete
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If
```

Reason why it didn't work might be that you used just `Rows(22)` without worksheet reference, so it referenced only `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Also tried that but when it comes to the point that I want it to insert 1500 rows in the current 95 it crushes again. I think that the for i function is the one that creates this delay.